# How to preserve auto-completion and avoid namespace in TypeScript Files which exports functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, export, javascript-namespaces

I'm currently working on a project where I have a lot of files like that, exporting functions like this:

```
// file: myFunctions.ts

// Function 1
export function add(a: number, b: number): number {
    return a + b;
}

// Function 2
export function subtract(a: number, b: number): number {
    return a - b;
}

// Function 3
export function multiply(a: number, b: number): number {
    return a * b;
}
```

Then other files import them like this:
`import * as CalcFunctions from './myFunctions';`

However, I'd like to organize my code in a way that allows for automatic completion and avoids changing the import names. I'm thinking of using a namespace like this:

```
namespace CalcFunctions
{
export function add(a: number, b: number): number {
    return a + b;
}

// Function 2
export function subtract(a: number, b: number): number {
    return a - b;
}

// Function 3
export function multiply(a: number, b: number): number {
    return a * b;
}
}
```

But namespace is not recommended by Eslint:
https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/main/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-namespace.md

So what is the best way to manage that?

Comment: *"However, I'd like to organize my code in a way that allows for automatic completion..."* Doesn't your current way (`import * as CalcFunctions from...`) do that? If you type `CalcFunctions.`, don't you see `add`, `subtract`, etc.? You should, and I do when I try it locally. (That said, I'd just do `import { add } from...` if I needed `add`, or `import { subtract } from...` if I needed `subtract`, etc. This is one of the great things about modules, you can just use the functions directly.)

Comment: Can't you import them like this : `import { add, substract, multiply } from "./myFunctions"` ? Yeah, you have to write the names of all the functions you import, but there isn't a namespace (and it is better imo than import *)

Comment: Yes I can import the function directly like this:
`import { add, substract, multiply } from "./myFunctions"`
But I have to know the name of the functions, and some names may collide. 

For example, I have User, and I have functions like getAll, getOne, and I use them like that : User.getAll() this is why I need import * as User

Comment: @SmallC - You can solve that with renaming imports, `import { add as addFunction } from...` But [again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77825281/how-to-preserve-auto-completion-and-avoid-namespace-in-typescript-files-which-ex?noredirect=1#comment137200474_77825281), what you have works for me. I get auto-completion suggestions in the editor and would expect any half-decent editor to do the same (since the type of the  module namespace object has those functions as properties). Are you saying you don't? With what editor? I've tried VS Code, and again would expect others to work the same.